# I would like to set a gallery of photos that is vertically centered on all sites

Tags: html, css

I would like to figure out how to get a series of images to be vertically aligned on the page so people can scroll left to right and view them. I have tried 'vertical-align: middle'as well as adjusting the top % to no avail, here's the current set-up

```css
.page {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/icymi_03.png" width="100%" />
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/moving_01.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/image082.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/image257.png" width="100%" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You want them to scroll left and right to view vertically centered content? I'm confused.

Comment: yes, like a portfolio, the images are aligned side by side left to right, I just want them in the center of the page

Comment: vertical-align goes for inline boxes , or the content of a table-cell. Else,  float kills display and vertical-align won't work even if it was inline-block elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `table-layout` , so you get a single line and can use `vertical-align:middle` from the parent container .

here is an example **without `float`** and okay for browsers as old as FF 1 or IE8 . today, `grid` and `flex` can do a similar job in that case. Play snippet in full page to check out `vertical-align` behavior

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.column img {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/icymi_03.png" width="100%" />
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/moving_01.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/image082.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/image257.png" width="100%" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

with flex it could be :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/icymi_03.png" width="100%" />
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/moving_01.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/94a2f217cbd0e1d3ae663764bfa3bef3/tumblr_oazuptRyRh1uz08p6o1_1280.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/gRAo4t8mm/image082.png" width="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/vbfmte2/QNbo4t8mh/image257.png" width="100%" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```